# ASP.NET Core MVC creates 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an ASP.NET Core web app using the MVC template, added my model class, added a corresponding controller, and ran `add-migration "initialsetup"` followed by `update-database` at the package manager console.

However, I have ended up with 2 local databases:

[image]

**Why is this**?

I had some difficulty getting here; e.g. for the controller name, I went for `ConsumerModelController` (singular) despite its automatic suggestion for `ConsumerModelsController` (plural) which ended up failing, but when I then went for the default suggested plural name, it worked...

Comment: What is the connection string in your appsettings.json file?

Comment: @Vima91 `"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-ApCHIS-86412CB3-F490-4579-9B6F-129F5A8D6CAF;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" }`

Comment: Try deleting both databases and execute `Update-Database` again, I should create one database? Also try renaming your database name into something easier to be compared.

Comment: @Vima91 Thank you! That did the trick. Your comments answered my question. If you would put them together in the from of a brief answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting both databases and execute `Update-Database` again, It should create one database? Also try renaming your database name into something easier to be compared.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the database file on my machine! Where is this file stored? When I click on the properties, there is no path either...

Comment: Your connection string points to `localdb` which is a local database to visual studio. If you have something like sql express for example, you can change your connection string and it will be created and migrated there. Please check this SO question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851516/is-there-a-default-location-where-visual-studio-would-store-my-database-tables-f